# Is bower_components special or unique in some way that it isn't served up on a website?

Tags: polymer, bower

I installed Polymer using the following commands:

```
bower init
bower install --save Polymer/polymer#^1.1.0
bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-elements
```

It created a subfolder called bower_components. But none of the files were found until I copied them to a different subfolder, and then everything started working.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to install your bower components in the "different subfolder" by default.  This can be done using the following in .bowerrc:

```
{
    "directory": "some/directory"
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`bower_components` is created when you invoke `bower install`. All deps in `bower.json` will be downloaded there.

Comment: They were downloaded there, but not served from my server until I copied them to a new directory.